# Deleting __MACOSX folder with PHP?

Tags: php, directory, delete-directory

Has anyone had any experience with deleting the `__MACOSX` folder with PHP?

The folder was generated after I unzipped an archive, but I can't seem to do delete it.

The `is_dir` function returns false on the file, making the recursive delete scripts fail (because inside the archive is the 'temp' files) so the directory isn't empty.

I'm using the built-in ZipArchive class (extractTo method) in PHP5.

The rmdir script I'm using is one I found on php.net:

```
<?php
// ensure $dir ends with a slash
function delTree($dir) {
    $files = glob( $dir . '*', GLOB_MARK );
    foreach( $files as $file ){
        if( substr( $file, -1 ) == '/' )
            delTree( $file );
        else
            unlink( $file );
    }
    rmdir( $dir );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found an improved version of the function from http://www.php.net/rmdir that requires PHP5.

- This function uses `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead of `/`. PHP defines `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` as the proper character for the running OS ('/' or '\').
- The Directory Location doesn't need to end with a slash.
- The function returns `true` or `false` on completion.

> ```
> function deleteDirectory($dir) {
>     if (!file_exists($dir)) return true;
>     if (!is_dir($dir)) return unlink($dir);
>     foreach (scandir($dir) as $item) {
>         if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') continue;
>         if (!deleteDirectory($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$item)) return false;
>     }
>     return rmdir($dir);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Which OS and version are you using?

---

You need to correct the paths to the directory and files.

```
// ensure $dir ends with a slash
function delTree($dir) {

    foreach( $files as $file ){
        if( substr( $file, -1 ) == '/' )
            delTree( $dir.$file );
        else
            unlink( $dir.$file );
    }
    rmdir( $dir );
}
```

Comment: Using MAC 10.5.8.

The server (which I'm deleting the files off) is using Ubuntu linux

Comment: Did you unzip the file from the shell? Or with PHP? What are the permissions on the folder? ie: `ls -l`

Comment: Could you post your PHP code, it may be an error you do not see.